# Ежечасное начисление баланса пользователя Django

Tags: python, django, celery

У модели пользователя есть IntegerField, и надо, чтоб оно с определенного момента каждый час увеличивалось на 1000. Знаю, что это делается с помощью Celery, но как именно не понимаю

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: у модели пользователя есть IntegerField, надо, чтоб каждый час это значение увеличивалось на, например, 1000

Comment: Документацию Celery уже читали? Что-то осталось непонятно?

Comment: нет, но вы дали мне очень хороший совет, не ответив на вопрос, так что спасибо, пойду впервые читать доки)